# ApiGen Windows Netbeans

Tags: windows, netbeans, apigen

I configured ApiGen on Windows and am trying generate documentation from NetBeans. Everything runs well after many errors, however I have a mistake, which is my destination is my desk from my pc. How can I change this? Whenever I try to generate documentation it never asks me for the destination again.

I tried uninstall NetBeans I do all again, but nothing.

My error is the destination of my documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Current NetBeans ApiGen plugin doesn't work with the new ApiGen v4. If you need to generate documentation using ApiGen, you can use command line to get it working, or use other tools like phpDoc which is working fine from the NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on the project, select Properties and look for documentation setting and change the folder there. Uninstalling NetBeans won't make any difference as this setting is stored in project as such.

To get an idea, have a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/apigen_support_added, on the 2nd picture. It might look a bit different now, but you should get the idea.